# Sort entity by subquery - NSSortdescriptor

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4, nssortdescriptor

I have 3 core data entities:

Entity A and Entity B and User which are related like

Entity A < ------ >> Entity B <<----- > User

I want to sort the entries in Entity A by the number of entries in entity B for that specific user.

I could do this:

- fetch all Entity A entries
- For each entry - fetch the number of Entity B entries for that entry and for the current user
- Count the number of entries for that Entity A entry store and then sort.

This though seems awfully stupid.

Is there anyway i could sort Entity A with a NSSortDescriptor perhaps by using a Subquery?
Or if you know any other way i should solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort on a collection operator so there is no way to us a sort descriptor to do what you want. Subqueries, like all predicates, simply find objects based on test, they don't sort them.

The easiest solution would be to add a transient attribute, say `bCount`, to `EntityA`. Then have the getter method return a count of related `EntityB` objects:

```
-(NSNumber *) bCount{
  return [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.bs count]];
}
```

Then sort your `EntityA` objects on the `bCount` key.

Comment: Apparently does not work with SQLLite stores as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090397/nssortdescriptor-with-a-function